# JMeter distributed testing throws Connection timed out

Tags: jmeter, distributed

Though I have tried the below steps, when I tried to start the Slave machine from the Master Machine GUI (Run-->Remote Start) getting the below Connection Timed Out Error                ***Connection refused to host: 172.xx.x.xx; nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect***

I have tried the following

1. jmeter.properties file, uncomment the line where server.rmi.ssl.disable and set it as true in Master as well as Slaves machines
2. user.properties file,added the line server.rmi.ssl.disable=true  Master as well as Slaves machines
3. To access the firewalls settings and create a rule to allow incoming connections for the TCP port 4000 in Master as well as Slaves machines
4. Add also I have tried to run *create-rmi-keystore.bat file*  as Administrator, but nothing happened. Once you run it supposed to ask some questions to type anything as long as it is accepted by the key/cert pair generation script.
5. Master & Slave Machines has Same Version of JMeter & Java at the same exact locations

6.JMETER_HOME , JDK, JAVA Paths sets on Master & Slave Machines

7.Master & Slave Machines are under same subnetwork

I am stuck here. I really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All configuration overrides should go to *user.properties* file
2. Any property set in *user.properties* file overrides what's in *jmeter.properties* file. Any property which is passed via `-J` command-line argument will override the property from *user.properties* file. Check [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) for more information
3. Default port where slave is listening for the incoming connections from the master is 1099 unless you changed the `server_host` property. Also you need to set `client.rmi.localport` property and open this port and 3 consecutive more for collecting metrics from the slaves. Check [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) for more details
4. Not needed given you disabled secure communication in point 2
5. All good
6. Not needed as long as Java executable in your OS [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
7. All good